# Installing node-gyp offline

Tags: node.js, linux, sass, node-gyp

`node-gyp` has millions of threads regarding offline installation issues, however, none of the solutions worked for me.
I'm trying to install `node-sass-chokidar` actually, which depends on `node-sass` and therefore depends on this package. I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04.
Due to the pc being offline, I cannot put the full log, however, in short:

```
...
gyp info using node@8.9.4 | linux | x64
...
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to hot node version: 8.9.4
...
gyp verb install version is no good; reinstalling
gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /home/user/.node-gyp/8.9.4
gyp http GET https://node.js.org/download/release/v.8.9.4/node-v8.9.4-headers.tar.gz
...
gyp ERR! stack Error: This is most likely not a problem with node-gyp or the package itself and
gyp ERR! stack is related to network connectivity. In most cases you are behind a proxy...
...
```

I've manually downloaded the above headers files, but I can't seem to be able to use them.
I tried to extract the headers and then `yarn add node-sass-chokidar --nodedir /path/to/headers`, but without success.
I also tried with the exact path of the headers (they are nested inside the downloaded directories inside `include/node/...`.
Another thing I attempted was to put the headers in `$HOME/.node-gyp/8.9.4`, which failed as well.

I wonder if I need to download the whole `node` source for the `--nodedir` path, however, I don't think its reasonable to do such thing for a minor sass builder library... it just feels crazy.
What am I doing wrong? No matter what I do the library tries to access the internet and fails to use the headers I downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sad truth was that I missed the `installVersion` file which wasn't present in the headers download.
Once I extracted the headers to `~/.node-gyp` and added an `installVersion` file containing `9`, the installation worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to setup an Ubuntu server with no internet access due to firewall restrictions. `node-gyp` for some reason tries to look for node-headers under their local cache and if there is no internet access it automatically fails. Here's what I've done:

To setup node headers for node-gyp:

- **Get the node headers file:** `curl -O https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.3/node-v14.17.3-headers.tar.gz` *(make sure you have the correct node version appropriate, and you need a machine with internet)*
- **Copy header tarball to offline machine** (approach may vary depending on your situation an example may be to winscp to vm)
- **Create the node-gyp folder that the library looks for if it's not already existing**: `mkdir -p ~/.cache/node-gyp/14.17.3` (PITFALL: in some versions node-gyp folder is under `~/.node-gyp`)
- **tar the file to node-gyp folder**: `tar -xf node-v14.17.3-headers.tar.gz --directory ~/.cache/.node-gyp/6.10.1/ --strip-components 1` *(make sure you have the correct versions here)*
- **create the `installVersion` manually**: `echo 9 >~/.node-gyp/6.10.1/installVersion` *(usually it is created automatically if you have internet access)*

Comment: This has to be done for any specific gyp version, correct? Is there any generic way?